# How to check the response from an API through restTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I know what the response is. But I got to be curious of getting to know about the response before its deserialization.

Below is sending HTTP Request to a certain API.

```
val response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity,
                DesignatedDto::class.java
            )
```

I used to have a problem with the above, cause the API doc was a little bit wrong so that `DesignatedDto` cannot have deserialized response. Now I solved the problem after checking the real response emailing API programmers.

But now I wonder as a programmer if there is a way to know about the response before deserialization without emailing them? Please don't say that I should use `String::class.java` instead of `DesignatedDto::class.java` cause I have an error like below

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.String] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token 
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 1]
```

Comment: You could call `response.getStatusCode()`.

Comment: @deadfish thank you. I didnt use that but it seems like getting HTTP status code is it? I want to get all response apart from status code

Comment: Please read the reference RestTemplate first. There are predefined enums: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html Just compare if `getStatusCode()` == `HttpStatus.XXX`.

Comment: @deadfish thanks but what i want to check is not whether my response dto is right or wrong. I would like to know how to revise my dto properties by checking the real response content.

Comment: If HttpStatus is OK then dto has been sent with success otherwise not- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#OK

Comment: @deadfish yeah thats true. But when status is not ok, how do i know in which way i should change dto properties so that i have httpstatus OK?

Comment: Usually server returns error code and error message/description. Does you server return such data? Do you know what is the example output from the server for happy and unhappy path?

Comment: @deadfish yep. The server to which i am calling an API gives me an error message. It refers to TOKEN. One of properties of the dto in concern is String type but this has to be List<Map<String, String>>. I have got to know about this after asking the developer through email. But How am i be able to know about this without asking the api developer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need ResponseEntity! Just use getForObject with a String.class

```java
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(URL,request,String.class);
```

**But** this won't work when the server sends **application/json** as content type. It will only give you a string if the body just contains a json string